# How do you get Aged Receivables By Contact in the xero-node library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xero-api

I'm using the xero-node library and attempting to get Aged Receivables By Contact. I cannot find any documentation on doing so as it appears that there is only one accepted argument: ReportID.

```
xero.reports.get({
  ReportID: "AgedReceivablesByContact",
  ContactID: "contactid" // <- this would be great
})
```

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, as the Xero API defines "ContactID" as being a required parameter for that report type. Are you sure you don't put the contact into "ReportID" and the type of report into "ReportType"? Although, the source to the "reports" function in Github suggests you can pass other arguments in and they will be passed through. https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/blob/ce693688c2e575a2d9cd3120ee62d2e2523a65e1/src/AccountingAPIClient.ts#L721

Comment: Thanks, it seemed it was a case issue. contactID not ContactID

Answer (score 1):

Solved - lowercase contactID key.